# Minecraft PE 0.8.1 fails to load server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Nexus 4 (OS: Android) says "Unfortunately, Minecraft Pocket Edition has stopped."  When I try to enter my actual server, which was made on my phone, it cuts of when Minecraft is loading terrain.  All my other phones work though.